# Data Execution Prevention has closed the program Ms08n.exe

Tags: windows-server-2003, malware, windows

I've got a Windows2003 server which I rebooted recently, and now is nagging me about Data Execution Prevention having closed the program "Ms08n.exe".  When I press "close message", the dialog just reappears, an error message occurs stating "Project1 encountered a problem and needed to be closed".

A [google search for Ms08n.exe](http://www.google.se/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_svSE303SE307&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ms08n.exe) turns up nothing, and the file is located in C:\Windows\System32.  Is there any chance that this file is malware?

**Edit** I just downloaded and ran Microsoft's malware removal tool -- it didn't find anything, so I deleted the file manually.  I'll try some other malware detection utilities and see if that doesn't find anything more.

Comment: For Malware detection and removal, I would recommend Spybot Search and Destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do in this situation is to run Microsoft's [Malicious Software Removal Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/security/malwareremove/default.mspx). This should detect the most common malware infections. You can do this by just typing "mst.exe" in the "Run" box or in a commandline console.

Read further details on this Serverfault question: [Some questions about the Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool -MRT](http://www.microsoft.com/security/malwareremove/default.mspx).

---

There is this [forum thread mentioning "Project1" as malware and "Data Execution Prevention"](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t186747.html). Here a screenshot what Process Manager shows if Windows doesn't prevent the execution:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something titled 'Project1'  would throw a red flag at me.  Usually that would be a string that you would change when creating a program. Perhaps it was made in VB6.

My suggestion would be, unless your team created it, get rid of it.

I say that because of the erie resemblance to this [case](http://securitylabs.websense.com/content/Blogs/3237.aspx).